# How to convert tuple type to int on python?

Tags: python, int, tuples, type-conversion

I'm  Python beginner. 
I want to convert sqlcommand result (`tuple` type) into `int` type. 
How can i do that?

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT timestamp FROM unixdb")
u_data = cursor.fetchall()

>>> print u_data
((1424794931452.0,),)
```

`u_data` type is `tuple` and I want to get `int` type from it.

Comment: Are all your responses contained within 2 tuples and have only 1 int? Ex: ((num,),)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you have there is a tuple inside a tuple. So you want the first item of the outer tuple, which is `u_data[0]`: the innermost tuple. And then you want the first item of that, which is `u_data[0][0]`. That's a `float`, so to get an integer, you want to wrap the whole thing in `int()`, leading us to:

```
int(u_data[0][0])
```

Comment: Is this really the best answer?  In this case, it works.  But presumably the OP wanted a means by which to extract a singlet from a tuple / list of any arbitrary depth?  Perhaps I'm trying to over-generalize, but it seems there must be a function to unravel an arbitrary depth, isn't there?

Comment: Sure there is: the one you write to do that!

Answer (score 1):

In case the result set consists of more than one timestamp,
you can get a list of timestamp(s) by:

```
...
u_data, _ = cursor.fetchall()
u_data = [int(_) for _ in udata]
```